# Laravel 5.6 connect refused using MAMP server

Tags: laravel, mamp, laravel-5.6, mamp-pro

I am using MAMP PRO local server with configured PHP 7.1 and mysql 5.6.38.
Install Laravel 5.6 using composer and edit .env file as the following,

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sample
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

and run command `PHP artisan make:auth`.
When I tried to log in, it returns `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.
I have changed `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`. Still, it returns the same.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: On my MAMP Pro installation, there is no root password, have you checked that?

Comment: Other projects are working with the same credentials

Comment: Check in `/config/databes.php` that the connection used is mysql (this line `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the MySQL port to your **database.php**:

```
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306')
```

Check one of the following things otherwise:

1. Are you sure you haven't blocked your port completely,
   for remote and local usage?
2. Have you double checked your MySQL port?
3. If you're using MAMP Pro, be sure to add the unix_socket key with a
   value of the path that the *mysql.sock* file resides in MAMP.

( Point 3 can be done with adding the following code to your **database.php**)

```
'mysql' => array (
 'unix_socket' => env('UNIX_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock')
)
```

Comment: Hi Remco, You are correct. It's working Now. Thank you very much.